# Is it a bad idea when writing a jQuery plugin to have an external Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uri

So I'm writing a jQuery plugin that will work differently with IE and other browsers.  It will use `data:` for file downloading, which isn't supported by IE 7 and below (I think?).  So for file downloading on those browsers, I would use PHP and send headers.  The problem is, quite obviously, that I would have to load up an Ajax request from an external site, most likely my own.  Is this bad practice?

Comment: What is `data:`? How do you download files with it? Which headers? How are they relevant? How does an Ajax request from an external site play a role here? -1 This question is poorly written.

Comment: Ajax does not allow cross-domain references.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it bad practice, it's prohibited.

With AJAX, you have the same-domain policy, meaning that if you try to perform a regular AJAX call to a website that the script is not hosted on, it will fail. For example, if you were using IE7 and your file was hosted on `somedomain.com`, and you try to make a request to `someotherdomain.com`, the browser will stop you. This is a security feature, mainly used to prevent XSS (Cross Site Scripting). You can read more on the same-domain policy and XSS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @Ray how should we know? we still have no idea what you were attempting to accomplish...

Comment: Well, your question asked if it was bad practice. Yes, it's bad practice. Beyond that, we have no more knowledge of your code or what you are trying to do, so we can't help you.